# RECORD_IN_USE_BY_WORKFLOW --- Prevent running WF rules OR Wait in Unit Test to Convert Lead until WF Rule is completed

Tags: unit-test, workflow, lead-conversion

I am getting this issue when running Test Class -

In my test class I am calling methods of class, where I am converting a Lead.

--- How can I prevent - OR - wait till Workflow rule complete's its task, and then call my methods to Convert Lead.

**FYI** - There are too many Workflow Rules to go through

Comment: When you are converting Lead wrap inside test.startTest() and test.stopTest() and then check expected value.

Comment: Its already in between StartTest and StopTest().

Comment: Is there a time-based workflow action ?  check this out http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/record-in-use-by-workflow-unable-to-convert-lead-that-is-in-use-by-workflow

Comment: Yes, there are too many on Lead

Comment: @Ratan - Is there any solution for this ? Should I wait for the answer or !?

Comment: Nilesh  I am sure what can be the solution for this. Wait for other's answer. check this out https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Unable-to-convert-lead-that-is-in-use-by-workflow-1327109102982&language=en_US